# How to make function work after another (which contains ajax request)

Tags: jquery, ajax, svg, .when, asynchronous-javascript

I have 2 finctions: first load svg on page, second change color of certain `<path>` in some svg.

**This functions looks like:**

`get_svg_part(category,position,part_name);` -- contains ajax

`svg_part_color(category,position,color,parameter);` -- need execute it after get_svg_part()

I have cases when i neen just load svg and not change color, in another cases i need load svg and change color of couple  in it. That's why i not used `success` or `complite` in ajax. Also i need do it on page loading so i put all (2 functions and call) before `jQuery(document).ready()` (if this information is necessary).

I tried to do it by `$.when` and `.then` but this has no effect:

```
$.when(get_svg_part('accent','bottom',' U+1F60A')).then(svg_part_color('accent','bottom','#FF7892',0));
```

Maybe i need make `svg_part_color();` in some sense asynchronous too? If so, then how?

***Question:** How to make function work after another (which contains ajax request)?*

Cool if this will work like:

```js
get_svg_part('accent','bottom',' U+1F60A');
svg_part_color('accent','bottom','#FF7892',0);

$.when(get_svg_part()).then(svg_part_color()); // just set a rule and not execute function here

// or maybe put this rule in svg_part_color() function
```

---

**Update:** get_svg_part code:

```js
function get_svg_part(cathegory,position,part_name){ 
   $.ajax({
      url: "img/icons/parts/"+cathegory+"/"+position+"/"+part_name+".svg",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function( data ){
       let rate_block_rated = movie_block.find('.movie_rating.rated'); //rate_block_rated
       let svg_symbol = rate_block_rated.find(".composite_rate svg ."+cathegory+"."+position);
       // prepend (insert) data to svg_symbol (accent bottom),
       // then find inserted svg, and delete svg tag (unwrap path)
       svg_symbol.prepend(data).find('svg').children().unwrap();

      }
    });     
};
```

Comment: *"contains ajax"* and *"returns ajax promise"* are two different things and would affect how `$.when` works. Need to see more of the structure of `get_svg_part()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as your first function **returns** a promise related to the ajax then you can do something like the following:

```
function get_svg_part(a, b, c){  

    // return the jQuery `$.ajax()`, `$.post()`, `$.getJSON()` 
    // or whatever method you are using    
    return $.ajax({/* options */})

}
```

Usage:

```
get_svg_part().then(function() { 
   svg_part_color('accent','bottom','#FF7892',0);
})
```